# How do you perform receipt validation for Android on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-billing, subscription, receipt-validation

I am following this guide: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/SecuringPurchases.html

to try and perform receipt validation. It mentions that I must implement this interface: IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase. But it also mentions for Android that I must get a public key from somewhere and split it into three parts. My question is where do I get this public key from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be provided by the Play Console of your application.

> To help ensure the integrity of the transaction information that is
>   sent to your application, Google Play signs the JSON string that
>   contains the response data for a purchase. Google Play uses the
>   private key that is associated with your application in the Play
>   Console to create this signature. The Play Console generates an RSA
>   key pair for each application. You get this response JSON using the
>   getOriginalJson() method within the Purchase class.
>
> Note: To find the public key portion of this key pair, open your
>   application's details in the Play Console, click Services & APIs, and
>   review the field titled Your License Key for This Application. The
>   Base64-encoded RSA public key that is generated by Google Play is in
>   binary encoded, X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE format. It is
>   the same public key that is used with Google Play licensing.
>
> When your application receives this signed response, you can use the
>   public key portion of your RSA key pair to verify the signature. By
>   performing signature verification, you can detect any responses that
>   have been tampered with or that have been spoofed.

source: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Verify-purchase